# Insert new span element after input element if it does not already exist

Tags: jquery

This is how my html code looks like:

```
<label><span>1</span><input type="radio" value="1" name="choice">
<span>Poor</span></label>

<label><span>2</span><input type="radio" value="2" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>3</span><input type="radio" value="3" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>4</span><input type="radio" value="4" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>5</span><input type="radio" value="5" name="choice">
<span>Great</span></label>
```

The second, third and fourth label blocks do not have a span element after input element. If in such a list, there is no span after input element, I need to insert an empty span tag.

```
<span></span>
```

So the output looks like:

```
<label><span>1</span><input type="radio" value="1" name="choice">
<span>Poor</span></label>

<label><span>2</span><input type="radio" value="2" name="choice"><span>
</span></label>

<label><span>3</span><input type="radio" value="3" name="choice"><span>
</span></label>

<label><span>4</span><input type="radio" value="4" name="choice"><span>
</span></label>

<label><span>5</span><input type="radio" value="5" name="choice">
<span>Great</span></label>
```

I am new to jQuery and this is what I am trying so far:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  if($(this).closest('span').length<1) {
    $('input').after("<span></span>");
  }
});
```

But this inserts several empty spans in each label block. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$(this)` instead of `$('input')` to target the current element in the loop:

```js
$('input').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).next('span').length < 1) {
    $(this).after("<span style='color: #f00;'>" + i + "</span>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><span>1</span><input type="radio" value="1" name="choice">
<span>Poor</span></label>

<label><span>2</span><input type="radio" value="2" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>3</span><input type="radio" value="3" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>4</span><input type="radio" value="4" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>5</span><input type="radio" value="5" name="choice">
<span>Great</span></label>
```

Also, you can use `next()` method to check if there is an `span` next to the `input`. I used next because `closest()` looks for the parent elements only, so it will not work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can comnbine the [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) with [.not( selector )](https://api.jquery.com/not/).

The snippet:

```js
$('input').not($('input + span').prev())
     .after($('<span/>', {class: "added", text: 'added'}))
```

```css
.added {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label><span>1</span><input type="radio" value="1" name="choice">
    <span>Poor</span></label>

<label><span>2</span><input type="radio" value="2" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>3</span><input type="radio" value="3" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>4</span><input type="radio" value="4" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>5</span><input type="radio" value="5" name="choice">
    <span>Great</span></label>
```

A different approach can be based on [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

The snippet:

```js
$('input').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    //
    // return only input without a span as next sibling
    //
    return !$(ele).next().is('span');
}).after($('<span/>', {class: "added", text: 'added'}))
```

```css
.added {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label><span>1</span><input type="radio" value="1" name="choice">
    <span>Poor</span></label>

<label><span>2</span><input type="radio" value="2" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>3</span><input type="radio" value="3" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>4</span><input type="radio" value="4" name="choice"></label>

<label><span>5</span><input type="radio" value="5" name="choice">
    <span>Great</span></label>
```